# How to 'explain' a runCommand?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to run `explain` with `runCommand`? I have the following query:

```
db.runCommand({geoNear:"Locations", near:[50,50], spherical:true})
```

How can I run an `explain` on it? I want to get the execution time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `explain` is a method on cursors. You, however, can enable the [integrated mongodb profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/):

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2); // log all operations
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 50); // log all operations longer than 50msecs
```

This will log details like `nscanned`, `nreturned` to a capped collection called `system.profile`, but does not provide as much detail as an `explain()` call does.

**In this case**, however, I think it might be possible to change the `runCommand` to a [`$near`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/near/#op._S_near)-query instead? That would give you full access to `explain`.

Comment: you mean, db.setProfilingLevel(1, 50)

Answer (score 1):

I guess we can't do explain for runCommand. Some of the runCommand give you the stats automatically ( eg. distinct command : db.runCommand({distinct : 'test', key : 'a'}) )

But, you can take help of the query profiler.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

Once you run that query, switch off the profiler, and check the system.profile collection for this query.

Answer (score 1):

According to [explain docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/) you can simply:

```
db.runCommand({
    explain: {geoNear:"Locations", near:[50,50], spherical:true}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers (from `mnemosyn` and `Abhishek Kumar`) are correct.

However, if you just want to see the execution time (like me), this is provided in the results along with some extra stats:

```
...
"stats" : {
        "time" : 2689,
        "btreelocs" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 1855690,
        "objectsLoaded" : 979,
        "avgDistance" : 0.006218027001875209,
        "maxDistance" : 0.006218342348749806
},
"ok" : 1
```

Well, I should have looked closer before posting the question :).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not a `runCommand` but I use something like this:

```
expStats = function() { 
    var exp = db.collection.find({"stats.0.age" : 10},{"stats.age" : 1}).explain("allPlansExecution");

    print ("totalDocsExamined = "+exp.executionStats.totalDocsExamined);    
    print ("nReturned = "+exp.executionStats.nReturned);    
    return print ("execTime = "+exp.executionStats.executionTimeMillis);
}
```